# Why echo request doesn't show in tcpdump?

Tags: ping, tcpdump

I have two network segments connected using a IPSEC-VPN tunnel :

- NET#1: a.b.0.0/16 with LAN gateway a.b.0.1
- NET#2: x.y.0.0/16 with LAN gateway x.y.130.1

I initiate a ping from a.b.0.1 to x.y.130.100 and started a tcpdump. This later shows echo replies packets but it doesn't show echo request packets.

Is it normal? How can I get the echo request packets too?

Here is a sample tests session:

The PING:

```
# ping x.y.130.100
PING x.y.130.100 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from x.y.130.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.87 ms
64 bytes from x.y.130.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.38 ms
64 bytes from x.y.130.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.27 ms
64 bytes from x.y.130.100: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=3.93 ms
64 bytes from x.y.130.100: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=1.15 ms
64 bytes from x.y.130.100: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=1.16 ms
```

The TCPDUMP:

```
# tcpdump -nn 'icmp and (src a.b.0.1 or dst a.b.0.1)'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:54:27.607103 IP x.y.130.100 > a.b.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22607, seq 1, length 64
13:54:28.608433 IP x.y.130.100 > a.b.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22607, seq 2, length 64
13:54:29.610167 IP x.y.130.100 > a.b.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22607, seq 3, length 64
13:54:30.614716 IP x.y.130.100 > a.b.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22607, seq 4, length 64
13:54:31.613417 IP x.y.130.100 > a.b.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22607, seq 5, length 64
13:54:32.615054 IP x.y.130.100 > a.b.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22607, seq 6, length 64
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer assumes Linux as OS.

The output cannot be captured as plaintext by *tcpdump*: it's already encrypted before *tcpdump* has a chance to see it and its *icmp* filter will not match. The input, which arrives encrypted is looped back as plaintext payload: *tcpdump* captures both, but its *icmp* filter will match on the second passage.

The Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking gives clues about this (you'll have to click for details):

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

on the right side (output):

- plaintext packet reaches *xfrm lookup* and is looped back as encrypted payload through *xfrm encode*
- *tcpdump* captures later the final result at AF_PACKET. This doesn't match ICMP, nothing will be displayed by the filter

on the left side (input):

- the encrypted payload arrives and is captured at AF_PACKET by *tcpdump*: this doesn't match an ICMP and won't be displayed
- the packet reaches xfrm/socket lookup and undergoes decoding through *xfrm decode*
- the now decoded plaintext payload is specifically sent through AF_PACKET: this time *tcpdump* will see an ICMP packet
- the plaintext payload follows the now usual routing

Actually in some cases (when IPSec compression is enabled and the packet is a short packet) there can be yet-an-other loop with the intermediate internal packet as *ipip* protocol.

If you want to get the outgoing traffic, here are some suggestions:

- you'll have to add something like `or esp`, but of course it won't be decoded, unless a proper `-E` option with the adequate secrets is set (which I wouldn't know much about). I don't know if *tcpdump* can also decode NAT-T (`udp port 4500`) this way.
- use *iptables* or *nftables* to duplicate packets to a dummy interface. *tcpdump* can capture on this interface instead.
- use *iptables* or *nftables* to log entire packets to the *nflog* facility. *tcpdump* can capture on this pseudo-interface instead.

Comment: Many thanks @A.B. Everything is clear now in my head. I'm using strongswan and its wiki explains very well the third solution proposed by A.B. Here is the link: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/CorrectTrafficDump.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a chance that the replies are going out on a different interface (perhaps one for IPSec?) from the one (eth0) that you are running tcpdump on?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have run `tcpdump -i eth1 -nn` and I got nothing. I have `lo`, `eth0` and `eth1` interfaces and `eth1` is the one that holds `a.b.0.0/16`.